# Magento 2 : success messages are not showing

Tags: magento2, session, global-messages

I am trying to add success message in my controller but messages are showing.

In my `controller` class, I have extended `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` class and using below code to add success message:

```
$this->messageManager->addSuccess(
    __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
);
```

Comment: Are you redirecting to another page after running that code?

Comment: At the end of the execute method, I'm using `$this->_redirect('contact/index');` to redirect and it's perfectly working.

But messages are not showing.

Comment: Does the regular contact form show the message after filling out the form?

Comment: Default contact us form is also not showing messages

Comment: So the code is not your problem then... Are you using any custom theme or did any customization?

Comment: Can you post your controller code here.

Comment: Suggested duplicate seems correct. OP, edit your question if it is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, but with an error message not showing up when expected after submitting the contact form.  The error message was not a surprise (I think it's because of not having email supported on the development server I was using). But, one development site displayed the message, and another didn't.

Finally, I turned the cache on for the site that wasn't showing the message and it worked. I think it may have to do with the ajax request for the message timing out since the page takes so much time to load without the cache enabled.